# How can I send a base64 encoded image with TYPO3

Tags: base64, email-attachments, typo3-6.2.x

I want to send a base64 encoded image via TYPO3 Swift Mailer, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
$mail = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Mail\\MailMessage');
$mail->setFrom(array($fromEmail => $fromName));
$mail->setTo(array($toEmail => $toName));
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setBody($body, 'text/html');

if ($data->attachmentExists()) {
    $attachment = \Swift_Attachment::fromPath($data->getBase64());
    $mail->attach($attachment);
}

$mail->send();
```

The mail will be sent correctly, but the attachment is not the expected image and not viewable.

The base64 property:

```
$data->getBase64()
```

representing a base64 encoded string of an image like:
    data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA...

So what can I do to get a viewable image as an attachment? Do I need a specific header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it works if the content type of the attachment is set :)

```
$attachment = \Swift_Attachment::fromPath($data->getBase64())->setContentType('image/png');
```